# Unable to reproduce org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ERROR

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, out-of-memory

We received an error from the customer end about an oozie job failing with OutOfMemory issue. The oozie job has three to four actions, one of which is a hive action.

The Hive action apparently perform a join which intern does a full table scan. Due to maintenance activity at the customer end, periodic purging did not happen and data got accumulated for few days. Which led to the hive action doing a scan for an additional number of days.

The below is the stack trace of the error :

```
2018-06-15 00:54:28,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader: Processing file hdfs://xxx:8020/data/csv/7342/2018-06-14/17/1/Network_xxx.dat
2018-06-15 00:54:29,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: Processing alias ntwk for file hdfs://xxx:8020/data/csv/7342/2018-06-14/17/1
2018-06-15 00:55:04,029 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: 7 finished. closing... 
2018-06-15 00:55:04,129 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: 7 forwarded 6672342 rows
2018-06-15 00:55:04,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator: 3 finished. closing... 
2018-06-15 00:55:04,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator: 3 forwarded 0 rows
2018-06-15 00:55:04,513 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator: 2 finished. closing... 
2018-06-15 00:55:04,538 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator: 2 forwarded 0 rows
2018-06-15 00:55:04,563 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator: 3 Close done
2018-06-15 00:55:04,589 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: DESERIALIZE_ERRORS:0
2018-06-15 00:55:04,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator: 1 finished. closing... 
2018-06-15 00:55:04,641 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator: 1 forwarded 6672342 rows
2018-06-15 00:55:04,666 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator: 0 finished. closing... 
2018-06-15 00:55:04,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator: 0 forwarded 0 rows
2018-06-15 00:55:04,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator: 1 Close done
2018-06-15 00:55:04,741 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: 7 Close done
2018-06-15 00:55:04,792 INFO ExecMapper: ExecMapper: processed 6672342 rows: used memory = 412446808
2018-06-15 00:55:10,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2018-06-15 00:55:10,852 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.<init>(DecompressorStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream.<init>(BlockDecompressorStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.createInputStream(SnappyCodec.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFile$Reader.nextKeyBuffer(RCFile.java:1447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFile$Reader.next(RCFile.java:1602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileRecordReader.next(RCFileRecordReader.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileRecordReader.next(RCFileRecordReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileRecordReader.next(RCFileRecordReader.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.doNext(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.doNext(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.doNextWithExceptionHandler(HadoopShimsSecure.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.next(HadoopShimsSecure.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

We received statistics about the data volume from the customer. Looks like they get 300MB data per day. The failed hive query has processed three days data, so nearly 1GB data. Altogether 30million records for three days

We tried to reproduce the same error in our lab set up, We loaded our simulated data which amounts to 100million (Totally 5GB data for five days) for five days, but still the hive query and its background jobs ran seamlessly.

Not sure why with the same map jvm parameters, we are not able to get OutOfMemory error. Kindly note that we do not have customer data dump. We are using our simulated data.

What might be the reason for us not facing the same problem as the customer in-spite for increasing the data volume five folds? Unable to understand the reason.

Below is the configuration :

```
mapred.map.child.java.opts : -Xmx512M
mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb : -1
mapred.job.map.memory.mb : -1
```

Comment: Try to increase the number of mappers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44885406/2700344